# Source of a malloc error when releasing a CGImage on iPhone OS 3.0?

Tags: iphone, malloc, cgimage

I've identified a bug while developing against the iPhone OS 3.0 SDK. Basically, if I create a CGImage from a bitmap image context, I get the following error when I release it:

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x1045000: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

Here's the relevant code:

```
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(100, 100);
CGColorSpaceRef cs = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
size_t bitsPerComponent = 8;
size_t bytesPerPixel = 4;
size_t bytesPerRow = size.width * bytesPerPixel;
void *bitmapData = calloc(size.height, bytesPerRow);
CGContextRef ctxt = CGBitmapContextCreate(bitmapData, size.width, size.height, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, cs, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
// we could draw something here, but why complicate things?
CGImageRef image = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctxt);
CGContextRelease(ctxt);
free(bitmapData);
CGColorSpaceRelease(cs);
CGImageRelease(image); // This triggers the error message.
```

The above example is self-contained and it's pretty clear no retain/release rules are being violated. I've tested this code on the iPhone Simulator under 3.0, 3.1, and 3.1.2. The problem only occurs under 3.0; it seems to have been fixed in 3.1 and later. **I have not confirmed the bug on the device.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem pointer seems to be the image's data provider. If I insert this line before releasing the image:

```
CFRetain(CGImageGetDataProvider(image));
```

then all is well on 3.0. But, if the app is running on a later OS, the Data Provider will be leaked. So you must check the OS version or simply ignore it (malloc logs an error message but it doesn't throw an exception or interrupt the app in any way). I've been using the following macro:

```
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
// 3.0 CFVersion 478.470000
// 3.1 CFVersion 478.520000
#define BugFixRetainImageDataProvider(img) \
    if (kCFCoreFoundationVersionNumber == 478.47) { \
        CGDataProviderRef dp = CGImageGetDataProvider(img); \
        if (dp) CFRetain(dp); \
    }
#else
#define BugFixRetainImageDataProvider(img)
#endif
```

Since I can't reproduce it on the device (I don't have any devices running 3.0) I apply this fix on the simulator only.